# mark mail as read without opening

Tags: macos, mojave, mail.app

When I get a mail notification I can hover it and I see options to "delete" and "reply" but I almost never want to do either of those.

Normally I want to ignore it, and mark it as read, or I want to open it and read it.

Opening it is currently possible.

But how can I mark it as read in Notification?

Comment: did you do any research on the topic ?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying Notification center pop up would be near impossible task, to add the "Mark as Read" option to the mail pop up.

It would require some heavy duty programing, but someone might prove me wrong and just do it.

But it is a good suggestion so send it to [Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback/), so they might do it in next release.

Comment: idk I have sent so many suggestions and never had any response nor seen any of it implemented

Comment: keep trying it might work one day :)